# How do I overloading operators to allow 2 * A in dart?

Tags: dart

I would like to implement a type A where I can write 2 * a. Is there anyway to overload operators so that this is possible in dart?

Answer (score 2):

You can not do `2 * a` because [`int`](http://api.dartlang.org/docs/releases/latest/dart_core/int.html) (the type of `2`) accepts only a [`num`](http://api.dartlang.org/docs/releases/latest/dart_core/num.html) parameter for its [`operator*`](http://api.dartlang.org/docs/releases/latest/dart_core/int.html#%2a). Here's the definition :

```dart
num operator *(num other);
```

However you can **define a `operator*(int mult)` in `A` class**. Thus you will **be able to call `a * 2`**. Here's an example :

```dart
class A {
  String s;
  A(this.s);
  A operator*(int mult) => new A(new List.generate(mult, (_) => s).join());
}
main() {
  final result = new A('NaN') * 16;
  print('${result.s} Batman');
  // displays NaNNaNNaNNaNNaNNaNNaNNaNNaNNaNNaNNaNNaNNaNNaNNaN Batman
}
```

Comment: yeah I'm aware I can do a * 2, but it's kind of unnatural syntax wise to do this. Normally we write polynomial expressions with coefficient up front. This just creates awkward APIs since it's normal to expect + to be commutative.

Comment: The commutativity depends on the object. For instance the multiplication of matrix is not commutative. `M1(1x3)*M2(3x1)=>M3(3x3)` but `M2(3x1)*M1(1x3)=>M4(1x1)`. However perhaps if an object does not handle the parameter type of the operator, it could be tried to _switch_ the call to try to handle the operation in the other way. eg if `2*a` could not be called `a*2` will be called if possible. You can [file an issue](http://dartbug.com/new) with that feature to get an official answer from the Dart team.

Comment: FYI, in the future you could perhaps achieve this `2*a` with [scoped object extensions](http://dartbug.com/9991).